# Offline collections - Meteor 0.6

Tags: html, meteor, offline

The smart package `appcache` allow us to improve the load time of Meteor applications by keeping in the browser *static ressources* defined in the manifest.

But that's not enough to run the app offline, we need to have offline database/collections as well.

Today, what are the best strategies to use offline minimongo? What is planned (or not) in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question by linking the [offline-data package](https://github.com/awwx/meteor-offline-data) for Meteor by Andrew Wilcox who is the author of the `appcache` package as well.

Answer (score 3):

Is Meteor (as excellent as it is) the right tool when there's a lot of offline? [SyncIt](https://github.com/forbesmyester/SyncIt) is one of the "edit locally then apply to server" libraries, but it's thought about as offline first. Disclosure: I wrote it.

Comment: This looks like a very nice library - great documentation too!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the collections aren't persisted offline. Meteor needs the ability to sync between offline and online collections as well the ability to persist collections offline. While its not [on the roadmap](http://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae) yet, hopefully its still on the minds of core developers.

Hopefully they see this question and put it on